# data sorting issue in funnel chart in vegalite

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-embed

i want to create a funnel chart and i find a vega spec with sorted data it look good -
[Editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJgpgzgxgTgSwA4BcEHsB2IBcIAicAhgO4AEAZgK6aYQA2ZMAFkXCmQpmQGoQDmRAPS8BRALT0EKCCAA04IiiK5QANyL0q0XAG1QABWQMusvAGEsUKvWVos8kJZopcARgAsABh9eAvnKGxlJ0uCAAilSaCBQIEGCOzpiuOG6+PgFBSCaheAByAuhoShjYCkkpABzpmSBG2SFmdXBFRQCe2YnoLrgAbDWBdcGmYeb06FBc-F09ON6+tfU5TQDqDuXdybgATANZy2EAYlzRAF7xM1upNQC6ASAQmDDoYFOqIG3vsQwJeEuNjhQHSamHQAFsTvRHFB0OxcJgbPQ-Pd6EQ2hA4HpQGC2ABrMIAIzYjkez1emGmOFAz3GmKpIG+9F+QwaIwUQM6eFBEMwmkc9AEj1+CPoSIUAA8vnEmaNNq52cCwgBHKLJaQlNSyBRQZQwfF4GCPGSY5G1HFwfUgGTi+UPJ4vN7060pUCM5kVQGKvAqohquwITUgU03BQkBBgFDMXAAVgyQA)

but my issue is that when i used unsorted data it not look like funnel [image: with un sorted it not making funnel]
is there any way in vegalite to make it in proper order as funnel look means by any sorting of vegalite it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is available in `vega-lite`, The editor config which you attached through link is already containing a `sorting` config in y-axis `encoding`. You can read more about the sorting config in [vega-lite documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html)

Now to solve your issue, I have interchanged some `Count` field values so it becomes unsorted data and added the `sorting` config with descending `order`.

```
"encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Pipeline",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {"field": "Count", "order": "descending"}
    }
  },
```

You can refer the [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABF1SAO4ACAGYNZsuINOwk6zKZqzTANT4EPfISMUqSJgoqKDESIIMamgA2qAAClq2rnBoIADCchAMgsE6cgGZVphoACwADJXlAL4KCUnCNmkAigwRNOY0cMqFbMVoAIxVlbX1OMlN6ABy5Gw6Qbq9-agAzMOjIInjjano8epzcwCe40uyJahDVRtbE7sZgmwQrmRnFwMV13WbDSlpAOoFJRFc5oABM62+tx2aQAYq52gAvbpvNAADnWAF1aiA4LIoGxlC80KAjiSQJ1bD09r8mkpMCd7rI2AgEYIAjInOTKYJqRk+qClGx1Kp1GlVNA8UTZK9qnKlIIkEc4GLUHEQMh1ABrNJMRwBPEE6WvUIgAmPVWgHl86F-emMtLM1myCIBQTkKVoWQ5QQ4gAe3K6vLSIJK9tO6AAjm1znQFqQOcEoDr0FA8ZgVSA5RtNSmQBm-WHcfjCcTTQWLlag3zQwEGRGQNGkLG8jQE9nMUpjDRlPQ0GIRkA) or the code below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Draw funnel chart in Vega/ Vega-lite",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Pipeline": "Consultation", "Count": 40000},
      {"Pipeline": "Qualified", "Count": 100000},
      {"Pipeline": "Negotiation", "Count": 30000},
      {"Pipeline": "Prototype", "Count": 10000},
      {"Pipeline": "Closing", "Count": 140000},
      {"Pipeline": "Won", "Count": 20000},
      {"Pipeline": "Finalized", "Count": 80000}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Pipeline",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {"field": "Count", "order": "descending"}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"field": "Pipeline", "type": "nominal", "legend": null},
        "x": {"field": "Count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": "center"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Count", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ],
  "width": 500
}
```

Let me know if this works.